# Reverse sorting a QStringList when using QStringList::entryList()

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a `QStringList` that gets all the files in a certain directory, and all the files are created by another function, hence, they are created at the same date. The problem is when I call "entryList()" in my `QStringList`, it orders the files from oldest to newest, and I want to reverse it.

---

```
jsonList = dirTweetJson.entryList(QDir::AllEntries | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
// dirTweetJson is the QDir of my files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override default alphabetic sort using SortFlag: `QDir::Time`

```
    jsonList = dirTweetJson.entryList(QDir::AllEntries | 
QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, QDir::Time);
```

you can  *reverse* the sort order using  `QDir::Reversed` along with your sort falg:

```
    jsonList=dirTweetJson.entryList(QDir::AllEntries | QDir::Files | 
QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, QDir::Time | QDir::Reversed);
```